# How to convert numerical value to json in GoLang

Tags: go

I have a Go container that calculates the total marks scored, and works perfectly.

For this to be able to be read by my proxy file, i need the return value to be json.

I am trying this however it isnt working:

```
// Find the total grade
    marksSum := 0
    for _, mark := range marks {
        marksSum += mark
    }
    
    j, _ := json.Marshal(markSum)
    
    return j
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the required json format? You have only converted a number to json, which is still a number represented as string.

Comment: {"error":false, "string": input_text, "answer":  markSum}

Answer (score 3):

You can create a struct of how you want to structure your JSON object.(variable names should start with a capital letters)

```
type Response struct {
    Error      error  `json:"error"`
    Input_text string `json:"string"`
    Answer     int    `json:"answer"`
}
```

Then just create a response using the above struct.

```
func main() {
    marks := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}

    marksSum := 0
    input := ""
    for _, mark := range marks {
        input = fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", input, mark)
        marksSum += mark
    }

    resp := &Response{
        Error:      nil,
        Input_text: input,
        Answer:     marksSum,
    }

    j, err := json.Marshal(resp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Errr : %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/iC484GS7GKS